# Spring JPA with Postgres - ID generation reset from start

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I was using following code to persist an entity to Postgres:

```
@Entity
public class TwEvent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String type;
}



@Repository
public class TwEventDAO {

   @Autowired
   private TwEventRepo repo;

   public void save(TwEvent twEvent) {
     repo.save(twEvent);
   }
}


public interface TwEventRepo extends JpaRepository<TwEvent,Long>{

}
```

It was working for ~30.000 records, but when I launched my app today, I get SQL error:

```
2019-01-13 19:57:48:432 WARN  http-nio-8081-exec-4 o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper:127 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
2019-01-13 19:57:48:432 ERROR http-nio-8081-exec-4 o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper:129 - ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tw_event_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(34) already exists.
2019-01-13 19:57:48:434 INFO  http-nio-8081-exec-4 o.h.e.j.b.i.AbstractBatchImpl:193 - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

Looks like Postgres started generating Ids from start and ignores already existing records. Restarting didn't help, neither using EntityManager.
App works fine with new clean DB. Any ideas how to fix a DB so it would generate 
right id?

SOLVED:

CREATE TABLE tw_event2 AS TABLE tw_event;

then I removed the original table and renamed a copy to tw_event. After that next ID was last+1 as expected. There was no need to change the code. No idea what caused this error though

Answer (score 1):

Better to specify the strategy like `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` if you are of course not using a sequence otherwise you would put `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)`, to make sure that the strategy being used to generate ids is always the same.

Comment: I tried. Now I get:       ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

Comment: could you provide the DDL used to create the table ? if you are using MySQL, you would need to have `AUTO_INCREMENT` in the id field declaration.